# WPF Application: Missing Resources when starting from WinForms App

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, xaml, telerik

I am required to make my WPF Desktop application available to be started from a WinForms application.

I am, however, using third party controls (e.g. from Telerik) and the application can only be started if I copy all the same reference DLLs to the WinForms application which is launching the WPF app.

The Exception is always that a file or dependent file associated with application.xaml cannot be found. Presumably because of the executing assembly.

I am not permitted to add references to the WinForms application launching the WPF application so how can I force my WPF application  to look in the right place?

It's here and also in the Resources section of my MainWindow that the problem occurs:

```
<Application x:Class="Application" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Expression_Dark;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the application is looking for the depending assemblies in the directory of the app where it is started - in the WinForms app directory and when not found, it throws an error. If this is the case, you can take a look at the [AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event to point to the right location of the assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. This is useful to know definitely but in this case the WPF application could be being started via a COM class so I don't have this at my disposal.

I want to try and force this during the Constructor of the WPF application or simply specify directly in xaml if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is too late to help topic starter however I will post the answer here as somebody can face the same issue. It took me some time to understand the problem and the fix is actually pretty simple - just call InitializeComponent() of your WPF application class before calling Run(). You will also need to explicitly set ResourceAssembly property (to the assembly where App.xaml resides):

```
var wpfApp = (WpfApp)Application.Current ?? new WpfApp();
Application.ResourceAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .Single(a => a.FullName.Contains("MyApp.WpfClient"));
wpfApp.InitializeComponent();
wpfApp.Run();
```